# How Does the submatch Command Work In Vim?

Tags: regex, vim, substitution, neovim

I came across this really nifty and handy command

```
:.,$/^\d\+/\=submatch(0) + 1/g
```

What this does is it finds any line after the current line, and checks if that line begins with a number. If so, it will replace it with the increment of its current value; however, I'm quite confused with how this is actually happening. I am guessing that the `\=submatch(0)` portion is what is doing the heavy lifting, but I cant figure out how. There is also a `+ 1` after the `submatch` which is acting as arithmetic, which is surprising to me. I would have thought that it would be inserted as text instead of performing arithmetic on the matched number.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the string starts with a `\=`, it is evaluated as an **expression**. In this case, `submatch(0) + 1` is evaluated as a *function*.

[`submatch`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#:substitute):

> The whole matched text can be accessed with "`submatch(0)`".  The text matched
> with the first pair of `()` with "`submatch(1)`".  Likewise for further
> sub-matches in `()`.

In the regex above, the whole match is actually the digits (the first number on each matched line). So `submatch(0) + 1` will add 1 to the captured match.